# Extract text between

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, grep

Could you please help me?

```
frame=48612 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.42 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48612 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.45 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48613 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.45 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48613 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.47 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48613 fps= 49 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.49 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48614 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.49 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48614 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.51 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48614 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.53 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48615 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.53 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48615 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.55 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48615 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.57 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x    
frame=48616 fps= 52 q=25.0 size=  113664kB time=00:33:45.57 bitrate= 459.7kbits/s speed=2.09x
```

Do you know if it's possible to remove everything except FPS={num}? I want to output something like this:

```
50
50
51
50
49
50
...
```

What I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -stats_period 0.0001 out.mp4 | grep -o -P '(?<=fps= ).*(?= q=)'
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -stats_period 0.0001 out.mp4 | grep fps | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,
```

Both do not work!

```
uname -svr => Linux 4.4.0-210-generic #242-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 09:57:56 UTC 2021
```

Also, ffmpeg return each frame per second, isn't a static .txt file.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `sed -nE 's/.* fps= ([0-9]+).*/\1/p' file`, see [this online demo](https://ideone.com/tze81K)

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -stats_period 0.0001 out.mp4 | sed -nE 's/.* fps= ([0-9]+).*/\1/p' ` do not work

Comment: ffmpeg logs to stderr, not stdout, so redirect first. `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -stats_period 0.0001 out.mp4 2>&1`

Comment: @Gyan but all rules in this post do not work, since there isn't a pattern on ffmpeg logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the progress option to pipe stats to stdout and grep that.

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -stats_period 0.0001 -progress pipe:1 out.mp4 | grep -oP "(?<=fps=)\d+\.\d+"`

Comment: do you know the regex to grep "time"? https://prnt.sc/1tbto29 (hours, min, secs, ms)

Comment: grep pattern will be `"(?<=time=)[\d\:\.]+"`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -stats_period 0.0001 out.mp4 | awk -v OFS=" " '{print $3}'
```

Comment: Not working! => https://prnt.sc/1t9ynsu

Comment: @KaiqueVortex : That should work. Edit your Q to show the output of `uname -srv`. Good luck.

Comment: Right. I can only work with the example text you gave in the OP, and based on that it works for me: https://i.imgur.com/Iw3KqEv.png

Comment: The ffmpeg command write each frame per second, isn't a static .txt file. Do you know how to output this while the running is running? If I put the ffmpeg output in log file, then using your CMD I get this => https://prnt.sc/1t9zu3j

Comment: awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767